# эмуляция нажатия клавиш на клавиатуре C# внутри программы

Tags: c#, клавиатура

SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");не подойдет так как работает вне программы и влияет на пользователя. Программа будет работать в несколько окон и именно в этих окнах нужно эмулировать ввод клавиатуры